# Can any one identify this insect from Lokhandwala, Mumbai India?

Tags: species-identification, species

[image]

I found this insect on my bed. I have never seen such creature before. Can any one identify this?

Answer (score 4):

It's looks like a Leaf-Footed Bug ([Homoeocerus Sp., Coreidae](https://bugguide.net/node/view/93)).

[image]

Source: https://www.flickr.com/photos/itchydogimages/17774939209

[image]

Source: https://www.flickr.com/photos/itchydogimages/6211603956/